# Making transparent some part of BottomSheet

Tags: java, android, xml, transparent, bottom-sheet

I want to make transparent some part of the bottom sheet. My aim is implement this.(Arrow is pointed) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80J7s.png) 
But now my app is looking like that. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5fvn.png)
How to achieve first image apperance?

My Code Bottom_Shee.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
     android:padding="4dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_bottom_sheet_title"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_set"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/set_item"/></LinearLayout>
```

My BottomSheetFragment.java class is like below

```
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL,false));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What is your problem? Do you get an error somewhere ?

Comment: Thanks for interest. I have edited the my problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the width of RecyclerView item. After that add a view on top of RecyclerView. Set the background of that added view as that slant shaped edge background using xml drawable. Set the color of the drawable as transparent.